# CNN training in bfloat16

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

Are there any efforts so far for training CNNs end-to-end with bfloat16 format? especially the convolution part, i.e. both multiplication and addition is done in bfloat16. Can this scale to large datasets such ImageNet? Intel has a published white paper about supporting bfloat16 in their next-generation FPGAs, where they claim that accumulating in FP32 format is essential to avoid losing accuracy on an application level. Would people building custom hardware for training have to stick with the FP32 accumulation?

Answer (score 1):

Most robust low-precision training frameworks rely on a hybrid of low-precision and high-precision calculations. I think the jury is still out on whether or not you can consistently train networks at purely lower precision (and achieve comparable accuracy). It becomes especially difficult if you try to train these networks on different hardware, because of the different ways in which precision is treated and optimized for.

Perhaps you're familiar already with [NVIDIA's TensorRT](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt) framework, designed to train networks in 8 and 16 bit precision. The "catch" is that it starts with a 32bit trained network and fine tunes it in lower precision. However, this *tends* to be considerably more robust than training in 16bit precision from scratch.